# Converting UNIX timestamp into date, hours, minutes, seconds

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unix-timestamp

How can you convert the UNIX timestamp (that is in the form of a number denoting timestamp) into date, time(hours, minutes, seconds) in Objective-C?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For output, use an `NSDateFormatter`.  To extract values for other purposes, use `NSDateComponents`.  eg:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1234567];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
int weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
```

Comment: It's giving me an error : 'gregorian' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: Replace gregorian by [NSCalendar currentCalendar]